# I cannot upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. However, I'm always getting the same error message:

"Checking for a new Ubuntu release"
"Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this issue.

It does not work using commands from the terminal nor through the Software Updater.

Comment: Have you held back any package? This might be the cause of such an error.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal then try this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

after all upgrade package installed
try to run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```